# Can I use pull request on Bonobo Git Server

Tags: workflow, pull-request, bonobo

Particularly, my team have a Bonobo git and we must use pull request as a important part of workflow but I can't pull request in Bonobo git even by command, what should I do now? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Pull requests" are not a feature of Git, they're a feature of sites like Github, and Bonobo doesn't have that sort of thing.

Commands like `git pull` work fine with Bonobo, but that's not a "pull request".

Comment: Thanks! My team will use another way :D !

Comment: @FesNguyen Which way your team selected.?. I have the same scenario.

Comment: By sticky notes :D